# Arabic UTF Encoding to Percent Encoding in NSURL

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, arabic, percent-encoding

am working on some mobile apps that send requests from mobile to internet via Http Requests

the problem is that i send Arabic chars in this requests as parameters so i have to convert them from

UTF-8  to Percent Encoding

i have  a java based solution here :

http://mrxprt.com/blog/?p=454

[at the bottom of post u will find English Details : ]

but my problem now with Objective-C , how can it be done ?!

Comment: How are you getting Arab text from the backend?

Answer (score 2):

Try either

```
NSString *result =[sourceString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or

```
NSString *result =(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)sourceString,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                               CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
```